# How to update in array of fields?

Tags: javascript

I have this initialization:

```
var myField1 = $('#field1');
var myField2 = $('#field2');
var allFields = $( [] ).add( myField1 ).add( myField2 );
```

where $('#field1') and 2 are input text fields of a dialog box, and I am trying to update myField1 so I tried:

```
itemDetails['myField1'] = "Test Fill Field";
allFields[myField1] = itemDetails['myField1'];
```

but it doesn't fill... what should I have missed or wrong?

Thanks in advance! 
Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized the `itemDetails` array. This works :

**EDIT after OP's comment** : Are you trying to achieve this ?

```js
var myField1 = $('#myField1');
var myField2 = $('#myField1');
var allFields = [myField1, myField2];
var itemDetails = [];
itemDetails['myField1'] = "Test Fill Field";
allFields[0].val(itemDetails['myField1']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myField1" name="myField1" value="myField1">
<input type="text" id="myField2" name="myField1" value="myField2">
```

Comment: I initialized itemDetails as = []; and in fact doing console.log(itemDetails['myField1']); I get "Test Fill Field"... the matter is, as I said, $('#field1') is <input type="text" id="myField1" name="myField1">...

Comment: doing allFields[0].val(itemDetails['myField1']), I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined"...

Comment: Please see the code snippet I added to my answer (which is working according to the results : field 1 value has been replaced by "Test Fill Field").

Comment: You can see my test example at http://nunzioluigi.com/testFillFields.php and you can see field is not filled once you open the dialog

Comment: You are not using exactly the code I suggested you. Once again, it works in the snippet, so you just have to write the exact same thing in your code and there is no reason it won't work. If you still have problems to implement this solution in your code, accept this answer and create another question with more details so that community can actually help you.